# Generate random 1-byte number after every microsec or nanosec

Tags: c, linux

I want to generate a 1-byte random number. But if I use `srand(time(NULL))`, it will take a gap of 1 second, but I want the random value to be generated every microsec or nanosec.

I even tried `rand_r(time(NULL))` but got compilation error:

> error: passing argument 1 of ‘rand_r’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]

Comment: Please show your exact and complete code as a [mre].

Comment: For starters, `srand` should only be called once. It sounds like you are trying to call that more than once a second which is not the right approach. For rand_r you  need to pass in a pointer to the seed.

Comment: and generating separate bytes at that rate is very inefficient. Better generate a byte stream and read the bytes as required, just like how `/dev/urandom` is implemented

Comment: These are not time-delay (`sleep`) calls, nor do they take `1` second to execute their code. Check the rest of your code OR share it here, someone will point out where the delay is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Call `srand` once, you can then call `rand` as often as you like and will get a new random number each time

```
  srand(time(NULL));
  while(1){
      int rnd = rand();
      doodle_foodle(rnd);
      if(wimble_wimble())
          break;
  }
```

as other have pointed out this is not necessarily the fastest way to get random numbers but they will all be random.

Comment: i tried this 

srand(time(NULL));        
random = (rand() % 255) + 1;

but it did not worked for me

Comment: @Vinaykumarsingh - what do you mean - it doesnt work for me? Please update the questiom to show what code you tried